# Mute gzip errors/warnings when using zgrep

Tags: linux, grep, centos, find, gzip

I frequently use the commands like

```
find . ! -iname "*test*" -o -iname "*foo*" | xargs zgrep -ie first.*last -e last.*first
```

I use `zgrep` because it *can* `grep` through `.gz` files, and if the files aren't gzipped it simply uses `grep`.  However I frequently get

```
gzip: copy.txt.gz: No such file or directory
```

logs that clutter the output of my searches.  Is there any way to mute these `gzip` logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect the command standard error output to the null device.

```
find . ! -iname "*test*" -o -iname "*foo*" | xargs zgrep -ie first.*last -e last.*first 2>/dev/null
```